# using ckeditor gem with rails nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, nested-forms, nested-attributes, formbuilder

Has anyone been able to use the ckeditor gem (https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/98) attached to a form builder object in a nested form?

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.1'
....
gem "nested_form"
gem "ckeditor", "3.7.0.rc3"
```

I extracted the problem to a very simple nested forms application, i.e.

post.rb:

```
has_many :comments
accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
```

So I try to use the ckeditor to edit comments. The view looks like this:

```
<%= nested_form_for(@post) do |f| %>

<%= f.label :post_content %>

<%= f.text_area :post_content %>
<%= f.fields_for :comments do |cf| %>
<%= cf.cktext_area :comment_content %>
<% end %>
....
```

A normal text area appears for the comment content. If I switch the "f.text_area" in the post part of the form to "f.cktext_area" the ckeditor appears for the post content.

No errors appear in the log when the form is rendered.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

did you generate ckeditor files with:

```
rails generate ckeditor:models --orm=active_record --backend=paperclip
```